# learn to make a module in the terminal

Tags: java, terminal, module

Trying to learn how to make a module in the terminal, Source: [chapter-11-modules](https://www.examsnap.com/it-exam-guides/chapter-11-modules.html)

I'm trying to make my own version of the file structure example:

mod / root / to / file/ Tasks.java

mod / modules-info.java

Inside the `module-info.java`:

```
module root.to.files{}
```

In the terminal I'm located in:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\mod>
```

entering the following line, to compile:

```
javac -p mod -d dir root.to.files/*java dir/*java
```

And I get the error:

```
error: invalid flag: root.to.files/*java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

I'm sorry for the basic question, but learning to work in the terminal for me, never works out as explained.

Comment: The guideline you are trying to follow has slashes, not dots, between the path components. (The second argument would be simply `*.java` if you want to refer to a file in the current directory, too.)

Comment: OMG me and my monkey brain, thx @tripleee